# Android SDK installer doesn't see java

Tags: android, sdk, installation

I recently updated to ADT r17. Ever since then, none of the android tools could see java on my system.  I could not launch AVD Manager, SDK Manager, Draw-9patch, anything.  The only way I could get an AVD to launch was to compile from eclipse without my phone plugged it.  Java is still on my system, everything was working perfectly on r16.  I can still go into the command line and type java and javac and everything works.

I uninstalled the sdk (by deleting the folder) and am attempting to reinstall it.  The installer doesn't even see java.  I tried clicking back and next again.  No dice.  I have in my system variables:

`JAVA_HOME   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin`

I just did that one after the first failed attempt to reinstall since that's what is recommended on the installer.  Did not help.  What was working before was:

`...F:\Development\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin;...`

I can confirm that at the end of the filepath, in the bin folder, java.exe and all it's other programs are there.  I'm downloading the .zip sdk, but I don't think that's going to help much, since none of the tools seem to see java even when extracted.  Edit: I can confirm, simply extracting the .zip did not help.

I'm on a 64bit system.  Everything was working with r16.  Any ideas?  Should I go back to r16?

Comment: do you upgrade to java 1.7 too? Android does not support java 1.7

Comment: I'm quite sure it does.  I've been using java 1.7 for months, compiling, using all the sdk tools, etc.  No issues till ADT r17.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason, adt r17 decided it did not like 64bit Java, even though r16 was fine with it.  Installed 32bit java and added that to my path.  Everything is fine now.

Answer (score 1):

You can reference here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=28196

I set `JAVA_HOME=d:\jdk1.7\jre\` (which is my JDK's directory) to solve this problem.